# PHP 500-error only occurs in server (production side) but in local is running fine

Tags: php

I have a PHP application, when i ran it on my local machine, it ran perfectly, no errors.
But when I run it in the server side, our remote server machine, it spits out 500 error.

The logic of the application is:

1. User will declare folder where the app will loop through the number of folders inside.
2. Will also declare number of files app will generate/create per folder.
3. And the character count for the description per file created.

basically:

```
for(x=0; x<foldercount; x++){
  for(y=0; y<filecount; y++){
    //creates file
    for(z=0; z<charcount;z++){
      //process here for details in file
    }
  }
}
```

basically, the 500 error will occur inside the creation of file. the situation now is it occurs in the middle, say I input 10 files to be created per folder, possibly the error will happen on the 4th, 5th or 6th loop.

thanks for your answers

Comment: Basically without real code there's no answer, it's just guessing. And check `/var/log` for error.

Comment: Please supply actual code. The supplied code is more or less meaningless.

Comment: suggest check server php version first, may be too old

Comment: Wrap your code in `try ... except` and return any exception's message, so that you can see it in the broswer's console and debug. You could also try temporarily returning 200 as the first line of your PHP  and see whether you get 200 or 500 . If 500, there is something wrong with either your URL, or your server's configuration. Also, take a look at the related question which you see on the right of this page.

Comment: actually, the code is too long for me to post here.. i forgot to include where the 500 occurs. wait i'll edit my question

Comment: With no code, it's just guessing. Probably, It's memory limit or time limit (It's common for shared hosting)

Comment: i've tried setting memory limit to both 3g and -1
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
ini_set("memory_limit", "3072M");

Answer (score -1):

Usually it comes when there is not try catch.

```
for(x=0; x<foldercount; x++){
  for(y=0; y<filecount; y++){
    //creates file
    for(z=0; z<charcount;z++){
      //process here for details in file
    }
  }
}
```

echo each $variables like $foldercount,$filecount and $charcount before adding in forloop. one more thing if there is any database "select query" error than it will occur again. so make sure there is no DB error.

if you don't know when it occurs try to do for loop for 0 to 3, 0 to 4, 0 to 5, 0 to 6 etc.

you will get specific position where you are getting this error.

Comment: actually it occurs in the middle of the 2nd loop or 3rd loop, basically whenever the file is created. in a loop of 10, it sometimes occurs on the 4th, 5th or 6th